# Jwt Authentication fetch request pending

Tags: javascript, node.js, express-jwt

I'm working on a blog application where the JWT is used for user authentication. if the user is valid then the JWT sends a cookie. To authenticate the user we send the fetch request with the cookie in the request header. It works fine when there is a cookie but the request doesn't return when the cookie is empty.

Code :

```
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

export const isAuthenticated = (req, res)=>{
    {
        jwt.verify(req.cookies.token, process.env.SECRET, (err,user) => {
            if (err) return res.status(403);
            res.json(user).status(200);
        });
    }
}
 
export const logout = (req,res)=>{
    return res.cookie('token',"",{httpOnly:true,path:'/',sameSite:'none',secure:true}).json('ok')
}
```

I tried to check if the request returns when the cookie is something not even the right one. It gives a response, but when the cookie is empty the request always stays pending.
[Project link](https://github.com/Sibichandru/Blog-Fullstack)

Answer (score 0):

In your controller method, you can check if the authentication related cookie is provided or not. If it'snot provided return an appropriate response to indicate it.

```js
export const isAuthenticated = (req, res)=>{
    {
        const token = req.cookies.token;

        if(!token) {
            return res.json({
                ok: false,
                message: 'Authentication token was not provided.'
            }).status(401); // Unauthorized
        }

        jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET, (err,user) => {
            if (err) return res.status(403);
            res.json(user).status(200);
        });
    }
}
```